# How do I make my DIV and SELECT elements stay on the same horizontal plane?

Tags: html, css, inline, display

I want to keep my DIV and two SELECT elements on the same horizontal plane.  I thought this

```
display: inline;
```

was the truth and the light, but evidently not as things are spilling over to the next line.  Here’s the HTML …

```
<div class="profileField address">          
  <label for="user_address_address">Hometown</label><br>
  <div class="field"><input placeholder="City" type="text" name="user[address][city]" id="user_address_city"></div>
    <select name="state" id="state" class="selectMenu form-control"> 
      <option value="">Select State</option>
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
      <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
      …
      <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
      <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
    <select id="country_country_id" name="country[country_id]" style="">
      <option value="0">-- Select --</option><option value="38">Canada</option>
      <option value="233">United States</option><option value="0" disabled="disabled">----------------------------</option>
      <option value="3">Afghanistan</option>
      <option value="15">Aland Islands</option>
      <option value="6">Albania</option>
      <option value="62">Algeria</option>
      <option value="11">American Samoa</option>
      …
      <option value="248">Zambia</option>
      <option value="249">Zimbabwe</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Here’s my JSFiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/5g8jxpa3/.  Any idea what I’m doing wrong or what I need to add?

Comment: Your fiddle looks fine to me. What browsers is the issue appearing in?

Comment: `display: inline;` is not a good choice here. the div will ignore the padding on the containing `input` and the height will change. Use `display: inline-block;` to keep it. See my answer please

Comment: @kirkpatt, I'm on Mac Chrome and Firefox.  To me, my fiddle shows that the state and country drop downs are on a different line than the city text field.  THey all show up on the same line for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [`display: inline-block`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp) on the `<div>`.

```
.field {
        border: 1px solid rgba(74,74,76,0.5) !important;
        display: inline-block;
}
```

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5g8jxpa3/1/)

**Edit: Side note**

Dont use `display: inline;` because the padding of the `input` inside will be ignored.

> While padding can be applied to all sides of an inline element, only left and right padding will have an effect on surrounding content.

Source: [inline elements and padding](http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/)

Answer (score 0):

div class="field" should be display: inline; in order to show all adjacent elements inline

Answer (score 0):

A div is naturally a block element, which means it won't allow anything else on its line. To fix this, you'll need to make it an inline (or inline-block) element.

The element in question is the `.field` div, which contains only a text input (for providing city name, it looks like). For some reason, you've set that element's display-type to `table`. The `table` display-type is a sub-type of `block`, and it also prevents anything else from being on the same line.

The display type you want is probably `inline-block` (which keeps the sizing properties of a block element but the line-breaking properties of an inline element). In the example below, I've only edited line 9 of the CSS.

```css
.profileField {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.field {
  border: 1px solid rgba(74, 74, 76, 0.5) !important;
  display: inline-block;
}
input {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: inherit;
  padding: 0.4rem 0;
  text-indent: 0.8rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.address {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="profileField address">

  <label for="user_address_address">Hometown</label>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
    <input placeholder="City" type="text" name="user[address][city]" id="user_address_city">
  </div>
  <select name="state" id="state" class="selectMenu form-control">
    <option value="">Select State</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </select>
  <select id="country_country_id" name="country[country_id]" style="">
    <option value="0">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="38">Canada</option>
    <option value="233">United States</option>
    <option value="0" disabled="disabled">----------------------------</option>
    <option value="3">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="15">Aland Islands</option>
    <option value="6">Albania</option>
    <option value="62">Algeria</option>
    <option value="11">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="1">Andorra</option>
    <option value="8">Angola</option>
    <option value="5">Anguilla</option>
    <option value="9">Antarctica</option>
    <option value="4">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option value="10">Argentina</option>
    <option value="7">Armenia</option>
    <option value="14">Aruba</option>
    <option value="13">Australia</option>
    <option value="12">Austria</option>
    <option value="16">Azerbaijan</option>
    <option value="32">Bahamas</option>
    <option value="23">Bahrain</option>
    <option value="19">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="18">Barbados</option>
    <option value="36">Belarus</option>
    <option value="20">Belgium</option>
    <option value="37">Belize</option>
    <option value="25">Benin</option>
    <option value="27">Bermuda</option>
    <option value="33">Bhutan</option>
    <option value="29">Bolivia</option>
    <option value="30">Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba</option>
    <option value="17">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
    <option value="35">Botswana</option>
    <option value="34">Bouvet Island</option>
    <option value="31">Brazil</option>
    <option value="106">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
    <option value="239">British Virgin Islands</option>
    <option value="28">Brunei</option>
    <option value="22">Bulgaria</option>
    <option value="21">Burkina Faso</option>
    <option value="24">Burundi</option>
    <option value="117">Cambodia</option>
    <option value="47">Cameroon</option>
    <option value="38">Canada</option>
    <option value="52">Cape Verde</option>
    <option value="125">Cayman Islands</option>
    <option value="41">Central African Republic</option>
    <option value="215">Chad</option>
    <option value="46">Chile</option>
    <option value="48">China</option>
    <option value="54">Christmas Island</option>
    <option value="39">Cocos Islands</option>
    <option value="49">Colombia</option>
    <option value="119">Comoros</option>
    <option value="45">Cook Islands</option>
    <option value="50">Costa Rica</option>
    <option value="98">Croatia</option>
    <option value="51">Cuba</option>
    <option value="53">Curacao</option>
    <option value="55">Cyprus</option>
    <option value="56">Czech Republic</option>
    <option value="40">Democratic Republic of the Congo</option>
    <option value="59">Denmark</option>
    <option value="58">Djibouti</option>
    <option value="60">Dominica</option>
    <option value="61">Dominican Republic</option>
    <option value="221">East Timor</option>
    <option value="63">Ecuador</option>
    <option value="65">Egypt</option>
    <option value="210">El Salvador</option>
    <option value="88">Equatorial Guinea</option>
    <option value="67">Eritrea</option>
    <option value="64">Estonia</option>
    <option value="69">Ethiopia</option>
    <option value="72">Falkland Islands</option>
    <option value="74">Faroe Islands</option>
    <option value="71">Fiji</option>
    <option value="70">Finland</option>
    <option value="75">France</option>
    <option value="80">French Guiana</option>
    <option value="176">French Polynesia</option>
    <option value="216">French Southern Territories</option>
    <option value="76">Gabon</option>
    <option value="85">Gambia</option>
    <option value="79">Georgia</option>
    <option value="57">Germany</option>
    <option value="82">Ghana</option>
    <option value="83">Gibraltar</option>
    <option value="89">Greece</option>
    <option value="84">Greenland</option>
    <option value="78">Grenada</option>
    <option value="87">Guadeloupe</option>
    <option value="92">Guam</option>
    <option value="91">Guatemala</option>
    <option value="81">Guernsey</option>
    <option value="86">Guinea</option>
    <option value="93">Guinea-Bissau</option>
    <option value="94">Guyana</option>
    <option value="99">Haiti</option>
    <option value="96">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option>
    <option value="97">Honduras</option>
    <option value="95">Hong Kong</option>
    <option value="100">Hungary</option>
    <option value="109">Iceland</option>
    <option value="105">India</option>
    <option value="101">Indonesia</option>
    <option value="108">Iran</option>
    <option value="107">Iraq</option>
    <option value="102">Ireland</option>
    <option value="104">Isle of Man</option>
    <option value="103">Israel</option>
    <option value="110">Italy</option>
    <option value="44">Ivory Coast</option>
    <option value="112">Jamaica</option>
    <option value="114">Japan</option>
    <option value="111">Jersey</option>
    <option value="113">Jordan</option>
    <option value="126">Kazakhstan</option>
    <option value="115">Kenya</option>
    <option value="118">Kiribati</option>
    <option value="123">Kosovo</option>
    <option value="124">Kuwait</option>
    <option value="116">Kyrgyzstan</option>
    <option value="127">Laos</option>
    <option value="136">Latvia</option>
    <option value="128">Lebanon</option>
    <option value="133">Lesotho</option>
    <option value="132">Liberia</option>
    <option value="137">Libya</option>
    <option value="130">Liechtenstein</option>
    <option value="134">Lithuania</option>
    <option value="135">Luxembourg</option>
    <option value="149">Macao</option>
    <option value="145">Macedonia</option>
    <option value="143">Madagascar</option>
    <option value="157">Malawi</option>
    <option value="159">Malaysia</option>
    <option value="156">Maldives</option>
    <option value="146">Mali</option>
    <option value="154">Malta</option>
    <option value="144">Marshall Islands</option>
    <option value="151">Martinique</option>
    <option value="152">Mauritania</option>
    <option value="155">Mauritius</option>
    <option value="246">Mayotte</option>
    <option value="158">Mexico</option>
    <option value="73">Micronesia</option>
    <option value="140">Moldova</option>
    <option value="139">Monaco</option>
    <option value="148">Mongolia</option>
    <option value="141">Montenegro</option>
    <option value="153">Montserrat</option>
    <option value="138">Morocco</option>
    <option value="160">Mozambique</option>
    <option value="147">Myanmar</option>
    <option value="161">Namibia</option>
    <option value="170">Nauru</option>
    <option value="169">Nepal</option>
    <option value="167">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="251">Netherlands Antilles</option>
    <option value="162">New Caledonia</option>
    <option value="172">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="166">Nicaragua</option>
    <option value="163">Niger</option>
    <option value="165">Nigeria</option>
    <option value="171">Niue</option>
    <option value="164">Norfolk Island</option>
    <option value="121">North Korea</option>
    <option value="150">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
    <option value="168">Norway</option>
    <option value="173">Oman</option>
    <option value="179">Pakistan</option>
    <option value="186">Palau</option>
    <option value="184">Palestinian Territory</option>
    <option value="174">Panama</option>
    <option value="177">Papua New Guinea</option>
    <option value="187">Paraguay</option>
    <option value="175">Peru</option>
    <option value="178">Philippines</option>
    <option value="182">Pitcairn</option>
    <option value="180">Poland</option>
    <option value="185">Portugal</option>
    <option value="183">Puerto Rico</option>
    <option value="188">Qatar</option>
    <option value="42">Republic of the Congo</option>
    <option value="189">Reunion</option>
    <option value="190">Romania</option>
    <option value="192">Russia</option>
    <option value="193">Rwanda</option>
    <option value="26">Saint Barthelemy</option>
    <option value="200">Saint Helena</option>
    <option value="120">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
    <option value="129">Saint Lucia</option>
    <option value="142">Saint Martin</option>
    <option value="181">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
    <option value="237">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
    <option value="244">Samoa</option>
    <option value="205">San Marino</option>
    <option value="209">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
    <option value="194">Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option value="206">Senegal</option>
    <option value="191">Serbia</option>
    <option value="250">Serbia and Montenegro</option>
    <option value="196">Seychelles</option>
    <option value="204">Sierra Leone</option>
    <option value="199">Singapore</option>
    <option value="211">Sint Maarten</option>
    <option value="203">Slovakia</option>
    <option value="201">Slovenia</option>
    <option value="195">Solomon Islands</option>
    <option value="207">Somalia</option>
    <option value="247">South Africa</option>
    <option value="90">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
    <option value="122">South Korea</option>
    <option value="68">Spain</option>
    <option value="131">Sri Lanka</option>
    <option value="197">Sudan</option>
    <option value="208">Suriname</option>
    <option value="202">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
    <option value="213">Swaziland</option>
    <option value="198">Sweden</option>
    <option value="43">Switzerland</option>
    <option value="212">Syria</option>
    <option value="228">Taiwan</option>
    <option value="219">Tajikistan</option>
    <option value="229">Tanzania</option>
    <option value="218">Thailand</option>
    <option value="217">Togo</option>
    <option value="220">Tokelau</option>
    <option value="224">Tonga</option>
    <option value="226">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
    <option value="223">Tunisia</option>
    <option value="225">Turkey</option>
    <option value="222">Turkmenistan</option>
    <option value="214">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
    <option value="227">Tuvalu</option>
    <option value="240">U.S. Virgin Islands</option>
    <option value="231">Uganda</option>
    <option value="230">Ukraine</option>
    <option value="2">United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option value="77">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="233">United States</option>
    <option value="232">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
    <option value="234">Uruguay</option>
    <option value="235">Uzbekistan</option>
    <option value="242">Vanuatu</option>
    <option value="236">Vatican</option>
    <option value="238">Venezuela</option>
    <option value="241">Vietnam</option>
    <option value="243">Wallis and Futuna</option>
    <option value="66">Western Sahara</option>
    <option value="245">Yemen</option>
    <option value="248">Zambia</option>
    <option value="249">Zimbabwe</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

It seems to me that you tried applying `display: inline` to all `input` elements; this is unnecessary because inputs are inline by default. The wrapper div itself is what was causing the line to break, so that is what you need to apply the rule to.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your required result by changing this single line in css class as putted here.

```
.field {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out I have made some changes

```
[jsfiddle][1]
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/5g8jxpa3/
```

Comment: I got a "server not found" when I clicked on your link